# Unit testing an observable in Angular 2

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angular, observable

What is the correct way of unit testing a service returning an Observable result in Angular 2? Let's say we have a getCars method in a CarService service class:

```
...
export class CarService{
    ...
    getCars():Observable<any>{
        return this.http.get("http://someurl/cars").map( res => res.json() );
    }
    ...
}
```

If I try to write the tests in the following way I get the warning: 'SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS':

```
it('retrieves all the cars', inject( [CarService], ( carService ) => {
     carService.getCars().subscribe( result => {         
         expect(result.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
     } );       
}) );
```

Using injectAsync does not help because it works with `Promise` objects as far as I could see.

Comment: The other problem is when getCars doesn't emit any values(for whatever reason) test passes(since there are no expect checks!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I end with a working example. `Observable` class has a method toPromise that converts an Observable to a Promise object. The correct way should be:

```
it('retrieves all the cars', injectAsync( [CarService], ( carService ) => {
  return carService.getCars().toPromise().then( (result) => {         
     expect(result.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  } );       
}) );
```

But while to above code works with any Observable object, I still have the problem with the `Observable`s returned from Http requests which is probably a bug. Here is a plunker demonstrating the case above: http://plnkr.co/edit/ak2qZH685QzTN6RoK71H?p=preview

**Update:**
As of version beta.14 it seems to work properly with the provided solution.

Comment: I think its because the `Promise` will not resolve if the `Observable` sequence is empty at the moment you call `toPromise()`.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md#returns

Comment: I am not much experienced with this Promise and Observable stuff but if I log something to console, I see that the promise resolves and logs to console at some point.

Answer (score 90):

### The correct way for `Angular` (ver. 2+):

```js
it('retrieves all the cars', waitForAsync(inject([CarService], (carService) => {
     carService.getCars().subscribe(result => expect(result.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)); 
}));
```

### Async Observables vs Sync Observables

It is important to understand that Observables can be either *synchronous or asynchronous*.

In your specific example the Observable is *asynchronous* (it wraps an http call).
Therefore you have to use [`waitForAsync`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/waitForAsync) function that executes the code inside its body in a special *async test zone*. It intercepts and keeps track of all promises created in its body, making it possible to expect test results upon completion of an asynchronous action.

However, if your Observable was a *synchronous* one, for example:

```js
...
export class CarService{
    ...
    getCars():Observable<any>{
        return Observable.of(['car1', 'car2']);
    }
    ...
```

you wouldn't have needed `waitForAsync` function and your test would become simply

```js
it('retrieves all the cars', inject([CarService], (carService) => {
     carService.getCars().subscribe(result => expect(result.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)); 
});
```

### Marbles

Another thing to consider when testing Observables in general and Angular in particular is [marble testing](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/writing-marble-tests.md).

Your example is pretty simple, but usually the logic is more complex than just calling `http` service and testing this logic becomes a headache.
Marbles make the test very short, simple and comprehensive (it is especially useful for testing [ngrx effects](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/testing.md)).

If you're using `Jasmine` you can use [jasmine-marbles](https://github.com/synapse-wireless-labs/jasmine-marbles), for `Jest` there is [jest-marbles](https://github.com/meltedspark/jest-marbles), but if you prefer something else, there is [rxjs-marbles](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles), that should be compatible with any test framework.

[Here](https://blog.nrwl.io/rxjs-advanced-techniques-testing-race-conditions-using-rxjs-marbles-53e7e789fba5) is a great example for reproducing and fixing a race condition with marbles.

---

[Official guide for testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing)

Comment: So, I found that if I do this, then specify another test later, depending on the order the tests run in the subscription from the other test is still active. What is the right way to address that? Unsubscribe at the end of the lambda function?

Comment: Note that async in jasmine is supported starting from 2.7.0

Comment: @PieterDeBie you're mixing `async` keyword (that is indeed supported starting from Jasmine 2.7.0) and `async` function from Angular testing utilities (`import { async } from '@angular/core/testing';`). In this particular example it is the latter.

Comment: That's weird, I use `it('', async () => {...})` without importing anything.

Comment: As I said, you're talking about `async/await`: https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async. This is Javascript feature, not Jasmine: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function. The only reason it is supported in Jasmine 2.7 is because Promises are supported in 2.7. Here we're talking about different case - Observables, and Angular has a special function called `async` which allows you testing asynchronous Observables.

Comment: async as a keyword  seemed to had fixed my particular case, but you are completely right.

Comment: What's the proper way to unsubscribe from the observable in the 'it' block? I'm seeing many tests in our codebase being connected and running the subscribe block inside other tests since it's not being unsubscribed. Just looking for the recommended clean up pattern....

Comment: `The correct way` - really? What about case when `getCars()` never emit? Your test will green but actually it fail.

Comment: @Jan'splite'K. I love the expression - great way to let everyone know how you feel and how much you disagree. In this particular question OP refers to an HTTP call made from within `CarService`. As I mentioned in the answer, `waitForAsync` will run all the async calls inside a special Zone and in case the promise is never resolved (i.e. observable never emits) the test will fail on timeout.  
In this case it is equivalent to `(done) => o.subscribe(() => done();)`.

Comment: @JeB or maybe english is not my first language and something get lost in translation :) - anyway, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 21):

https://angular.io/guide/testing currently shows a few ways. Here is one:

> ```
> it('#getObservableValue should return value from observable',
>     (done: DoneFn) => {
>        service.getObservableValue().subscribe(value => {
>        expect(value).toBe('observable value');
>        done();
>     });
> });
> ```

Comment: Even this method works, but I think using async() is the better way.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend this approach, which I think is more elegant:

```
expectAsync(carService.getCars().toPromise()).toBeResolvedWith(myExpectedValue);
```

You can also provide your own async matchers using: [Jasmine Matcher](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/custom_matcher)

Answer (score 2):

The way I've managed to get it to work is to subscribe and call done after the expects.

```
it('should equal bar', (done: any) => {
 bar.getFoo().subscribe(v => {
  expect(v).toBe('foo');
  done();
 });
});
```

Update:
Another way of doing this that I've found useful is to convert the observable into a promise if you know you only need one value. You can convert using either lastValueFrom or firstValueFrom. Then use a regular async/await structure for the test.

```
it('should equal bar', async () => {
 const result = await firstValueFrom(bar.getFoo())
 expect(result).toBe('foo')
});
```

It leads to a slightly shorter expect and setup so this was something we preferred at my old project.

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTestCompleter` is deprecated https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5443. `injectAsync` replaced it 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4715#issuecomment-149288405
<strike>but `injectAsync` is now also deprecated</strike>
`injectAsync` is not deprecated anymore https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/5721 (see also comment from @ErdincGuzel)

```
it('retrieves all the cars', injectAsync( [CarService], ( carService ) => {
     var c = PromiseWrapper.completer();
     carService.getCars().subscribe( result => {         
         expect(result.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
         c.resolve();
     } ); 
     return c.promise;      
}) );
```

Comment: I had seen the examples of `AsyncTestCompleter` in angular repo but it seems like `AsyncTestCompleter` is internal to angular and not found in public API.

Comment: I updated my answer. I haven't tried this because I don't use TS myself.

Comment: The updated answer does not work unfortunately. inject method does not allow to return Promise values. By the way the injectAsync is again undeprecated with [#5721](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/5721)