# How to test async Call for Angular service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, jasmine-async

I have the following Angular service method

```
  updateStorage(): void {
    this.authServiceRef = this.authService.authRequest('storage', {}).subscribe((result) => {
      this.storage = this.buildStorage(result);
      this.storageUpdate.emit({ ...this.storage });
    });
  }
```

and facing difficulties to test that piece of code

My test looks like

```
  fit('Update Storage Status', inject([AuthService], fakeAsync((authService: AuthService) => {
    spyOn(authService, 'authRequest').and.returnValue(Observable.of(storageStatus_50GB_LowUsageTest));
    spyOn(storageService, 'buildStorage');
    spyOn(storageService.storageUpdate, 'emit');

    
    storageService.updateStorage();
    tick(1000);


    expect(authService.authRequest).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith('files', 'storage', {});
    expect(storageService.buildStorageStatus).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(storageService.storageStatusUpdate.emit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    //  FAILS - storageService.storage is undefined
    expect(storageService.storage.size).toEqual(storageStatus_50GB_LowUsageTest.size)
    expect(storageService.storage.maximum).toEqual(storageStatus_50GB_LowUsageTest.maximum);
    expect(storageService.storage.usedPercentage).toEqual(0.4)
    expect(storageService.storage.storageUsedSafeRound).toEqual(4);

  })));
```

All spy calls are fine and they pass but the **storageService.storage** is **undefined**

How to test the code inside a subscription function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit testing an observable in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607990/unit-testing-an-observable-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1):

Using spyOn on the `buildStorage` method will replace the called method with a stub (which will return `undefined)`. In this case you want to use the `callThrough` or `and.returnValue` to ensure it returns the value you are expecting

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue