# Testing async function with observable

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to write a unit test for a method I have. The method is async and uses an observable to set a property's value. After that method is done I'd like to be sure that property have a length of 10.

The error I get is: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

**Component**

```
  async someMethod() {
    const someObservable = await new Observable(
      (observer: Observer<any>) => {
       ...
      }
    );

    someObservable.subscribe((data) => {
      this.someVariable = data;
    });
  };
```

**Spec**

```
  it('should set someVariable', async () => {
    await component.someMethod();
    expect(component.someVariable.length).toEqual(10);
  });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607990/unit-testing-an-observable-in-angular-2

Comment: @R.Richards this isn't exactly what my code is doing as I define the observable inside this method so i can't simply call it